# How to change View content in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I've been trying to replace a view in **React Native**, but to no success. The app closes without errors whenever I try `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {handleChangeMyView();}}>` :

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it work?

Thank you all in advance.

```
import React, {
  useState
} from 'react';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import MyInitialView from './MyInitialView';

const SiteContainer = () => {
  let MyDynamicView = () => {
    return (
      <View></View>
    );
  };

  const [MyDynamicViewArea, setMyDynamicViewArea] = useState(MyInitialView);

  const handleChangeMyView = () => {
    setMyDynamicViewArea(MyDynamicView);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.siteContainer}>
      {MyDynamicViewArea}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {handleChagnStaceMyView();}}>
        <View>
          <FontAwesome name="quote-left"></FontAwesome>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default SiteContainer;
```

**MyInitialView**  :

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default function MyInitialView() {
  return (
    <View></View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect name of function in onPress of TouchableOpacity.
Change this

```
onPress={() => {handleChagnStaceMyView();}}
```

to

```
onPress={() => {handleChangeMyView();}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are calling wrong function `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {handleChagnStaceMyView();}}>`
make it right as `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {handleChangeMyView();}}>`

good luck

I wonder you are not getting error like `handleChagnStaceMyView is not defined`